# A tool or online service that shows my traceroute results on the map

Tags: gratis, networking, maps

I want a program or a site where I can insert traceroute results like this

```
 1  192.168.89.1  146.962 ms  149.202 ms  159.185 ms
 2  104.131.223.254  159.878 ms 104.131.223.253  159.561 ms  159.599 ms
 3  192.241.164.237  159.069 ms 192.241.164.241  158.918 ms  158.910 ms
 4  162.243.191.255  159.422 ms  159.446 ms 192.241.164.249  277.308 ms
 5  162.243.191.255  159.440 ms 209.85.244.139  159.509 ms 162.243.191.255  159.432 ms
 6  8.8.8.8  159.447 ms  131.126 ms 209.85.244.129  128.908 ms
```

and it graphically shows the hops on maps, with red links (lossy, high added latency), green good lines and so on.

Typical visual traceroute tools (like [this](http://en.dnstools.ch/visual-traceroute.html) or [this](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/)) only allow entering the destination IP and do both tracing, converting from IPs to locations and visualisation in one move. I want just the second and third steps by providing the list of IPs manually.

No budget, online preferred. Alternatively some simple GUI tool (preferrably running on Linux) that combines traceroute, whois and maps.

Comment: Start with Googling [visual traceroute](https://www.google.nl/search?q=visual+traceroute). I don't have the time right now.

Comment: @JanDoggen, Typical visual traceroute site bundles doing the traceroute and displaying the result on map, i.e. I can only enter a destination IP address. I want just the second part: visualisation.